# Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode with Scala - case class cannot inherit Java class

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, lombok

I have a Java class, with a lombok generated `equals` and `hashCode`

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyJavaClass {
    private final String foo;
}
```

And a Scala case class which inherits this:

```scala
case class MyScalaCaseClass(foo: String, bar: String) extends MyJavaClass(foo)
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
[scalac-2.12] .../MyScalaCaseClass.scala:5: error: overriding method canEqual in trait Equals of type (that: Any)Boolean;
[scalac-2.12]  method canEqual in class MyJavaClass of type (x$1: Any)Boolean has weaker access privileges; it should be public
[scalac-2.12] case class MyScalaCaseClass(foo: String, bar: String) extends MyJavaClass(foo)
[scalac-2.12]            ^
[scalac-2.12] one error found
```

It seems that this issue seems to be caused by a mismatch of access privilages:

- I'm using Lombok 1.16, and it seems since 1.14 the `canEqual` method generated by Lombok is `protected` ([the Lombok docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) mention this too)
- The [Scala `Equals` trait](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Equals.scala) has a `public` `canEqual` method.

The [Lombok Docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) explicitly mention interoperability with Scala case classes:

> If all classes in a hierarchy are a mix of scala case classes and classes with lombok-generated equals methods, all equality will 'just work'.

Is there anything I'm missing here? I can work around this by using a `class` rather than a `case class`, but then I'd have to implement `equals` which doesn't seem so elegant.

Comment: Scala-Java interior has always been iffy. You may try opening a ticket against Lombok GitHub, but they are slow, and I wouldn’t recommend holding your breath for an answer. Your best bet might be not using a case class, and overriding equals yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override `canEqual` method in `MyJavaClass` for replacing **lombok** generated `canEqual` method like:

```
public boolean canEqual(Object other) {
    return other instanceof MyJavaClass;
}
```

This way will keep `canEqual` method has the `public` modifier.